# How to raise an event on usercontrol from aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have usercontrol with couple of buttons in it, I wanted to use the user control in page and instead of displaying the button which is on usercontrol I wanted to click a button on the page which raises button click event on the usercontrol.

PageA_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
should call
   UserControl_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
public partial class UserControls_DEMO : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public void UserControl_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}


public partial class ASPXPAGE : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void PageA_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Call UserControl_Button_Click here
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow - could you post some code to describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: see the original post.I just edited.

Comment: I'm still a little confused - can you not just put UserControl_Button_Click(sender, e) inside of PageA_Button_Click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the first button's onclick event call the second buttons, I would just add this tag to the first button's HTML:

```
OnClientClick="document.getElementById('INSERT_SECOND_BUTTON_ID_HERE').click();"
```

Slightly different approach to what you are wanting to do.